# Error compiling Sass in Angular CLI

Tags: sass, angular-cli

For some reason, the angular cli does not compile the sass file. This is my sass file:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

/* Variáveis */
$bodyColor: #f1f1f1;

body { background: $bodyColor; margin: 0px; }

header{ background-color: #FFF059; width:100%; height: 54px; border-bottom: 1px solid #D9D9D9; }

.logo{ margin-top:4px; }
```

And this here is the error presented in the console:

**ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.sass
Module build failed:
.logo{ margin-top:4px; }
                        ^
      Invalid CSS after "...rgin-top:4px; }": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{}"
      in /Users/danielswater/Documents/MercadoLivre/src/styles.sass (line 10, column 26)
 @ ./src/styles.sass 4:14-187
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass**

What is wrong? It would be a problem with the angular CLI

Comment: are you using it in your component css property or like a global css

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problem in `angular2`

First you need to make sure, your `.angular-cli.json` has `.scss` as the defaut style extension.

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
```

Aftet that, I manually installed `node-sass` and `sass-loader` which fixed my errors

```
npm i -D node-sass sass-loader
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to include your scss file e.g. 'bootstrap.scss' in your .angular-cli.json file as follows :

```
"apps": [
{

...

"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
  "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]

...

}
]
```

and then restart your

```
ng serve
```